In ECHARTS how to start with a hidden serie and then make it visible with custom legend
How start with a hidden serie on graph and then display it with a custom legend button like
<div>
  <input type="button" value="hide show NAME_OF_THE_SERIE" id="buttonid">
</div>

<script>
button = document.body.querySelector('#buttonid');
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {   
    myChart.dispatchAction({
      type: "legendToggleSelect",
      name: "NAME_OF_THE_SERIE"
    });
    console.log(myChart.getOption().series);
});
</script>

Here the link of the codepen.io where I took this
Now, like you see in console (if you implement this method) the object with the serie name "NAME_OF_THE_SERIE" returned with chart.getOption().series it's exactly the same when the serie is hidden and when it's showed on graph.
So also how to know if a serie it's hidden?

Not sure what you are asking for. legend.selected property? Example

@Matthias Mertens yeah exactly. Tnx. Works good. legend { selected: {'NAME_OF_THE_SERIE': false,} }. It's what i was searching for. There's also a way to know if the serie is hidden? I can't see in chart.getOption().series the property "legend". It's for change the style of the external button that enables and disables the serie when the serie is hidden or show (serie.itemStyle.coloror grey).

You can find the information in the chart object itself under _componentsMap. In the given example it is at myChart['_componentsMap']['_ec_\u0000series\u00000\u00000_legend.plain'].__model.option.selected for me.

@Matthias Mertens Sorry, too much informations that I don't understand. Could be your comment it's the answer but how to understand if a series is shows from the javascript code? Can u make a simple example like a codepen.io or a jsfiddle that uses a button to know if the serie "NAME_OF_THE_SERIE" it's show or hidden please? Also write something to understand it's good. The object chart._componentsMap it's full of string. A boolean it's needed: it's diplayed or not (by using the serie name). I can't find nothing about that in documentations. TNX

Example

WHOOAHH TNX @Matthias Mertens it's exactly what I was looking for. Perfect example. How complicated. I swear I couldn't have done that. Thank you so much. It would have been much easier to put a value in chart.getOption().series than in _componentsMap/ObjectsWithIdIncomprehensible/__model/type. I don't know how you knew that, but thanks. In any case I can't find anything it in the documentation. Thanks again

P.S. The absurdity is that if nothing is specified in the assignment (show/hidden) in option legend.selected the the element is completely missing.

Other example (using your example as base) for who it's reading https://jsfiddle.net/eLp20ofy/1/

You can use the legend.selected setting to hide/show specific series by default or to modify their visibility status in response to an external event.
const option = {
  legend: {
    selected: {
      // serieName: true (show) / false (hide)
      serieName: false,
    },
  },
};



/**
 ** Initialize
 */
const chartDom = document.getElementById('chart');
const chart = echarts.init(chartDom);

/**
 ** Data
 */
const categoryData = ['category0', 'category1', 'category2', 'category3', 'category4'];
const barData = [30, 50, 70, 60, 80];

/**
 ** Option
 */
const option = {
  legend: {
    selected: {
      // serieName: true (show) / false (hide)
      serieName: false,
    },
  },
  yAxis: {},
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: categoryData,
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name: 'serieName',
      data: barData,
    },
  ]
};

/**
 ** Render Chart
 */
chart.setOption(option);

/**
 ** Change series legend selected status by external function
 */
document.getElementById('toggleVisibility').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const legendSelected = option.legend.selected['serieName'];
  option.legend.selected['serieName'] = ! legendSelected;
  chart.setOption(option, true);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.5.0/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha512-k37wQcV4v2h6jgYf5IUz1MoSKPpDs630XGSmCaCCOXxy2awgAWKHGZWr9nMyGgk3IOxA1NxdkN8r1JHgkUtMoQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button id="toggleVisibility">Toggle legend visibility</button>

<div id="chart" style="width: 650px; height: 250px;"></div>



